# bxSlider just shows a bullet and my first image

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I know very basic html and css. And I'll probably sound stupid but anyway, I'd really like to know what I'm missing here.When I put my code in jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/FLuRH/17/) it works fine.But on my file, it just shows a single image and a bullet on the top left hand corner. I've been all over the place and I've only found something here that makes me 'check' my directory and linking.

**I've linked to:**

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js
js/jquery.bxslider.min.js
js/jquery.bxslider.css
```

**Image list:**
I used the .svg format and the same height/width, they have links to corresponding pages via a href, and are enclosed in list tags.
(I have about 10 images)

**The Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        speed:300,
        auto: true,
        autoHover: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure the css is in js folder? `js/jquery.bxslider.css`

Comment: What's the difference between the code on the fiddle and your code

Comment: is jquery link commented?

Comment: time for the developers console...